# Is it possible to swap CPU from one laptop to another?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I have an [HP G42](https://support.hp.com/lt-en/document/c02625184) similar to my mom’s [Compaq CQ42](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/compaq-presario-cq42-100-notebook-pc-series/4121902/model/4188304/drivers). My mom’s laptop is equipped with Intel i5 430M while mine is i3 380M. Is it possible that I could swap my laptop’s CPU with her laptop’s CPU?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. If you want an actual answer, please [edit] your question to state the *exact model numbers* of both CPUs. Just the CPU family isn't enough to tell with certainty.

Comment: I've edited it!

Comment: Great! I don't have a ready answer for you, but assuming those model numbers are accurate (it's been a long while since I stayed up to date on Intel's product offerings), this should be enough to enable someone to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes!**

*When performing this procedure, especially if it's your first time doing computer maintenance like this, you risk damaging both laptops permanently. Follow the manual's instructions **exactly**.*

Oddly enough, both laptops are so similar that [they share the same manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02623161.pdf). See page 94 [of the manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02623161.pdf) for processor removal guide.

This [video on YouTube (“Laptop CPU install, how to upgrade your Laptop CPU”)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb_RSEf-br0) also includes some helpful information, but don't follow it exactly, only use it for tips.

More information about *why* this is possible in this case:

1. Both CPUs use the same socket, which means their physical footprint is identical.
2. Both laptops have very similar (if not identical) motherboards.

Keep in mind this is not usually the case! Some laptops even have soldered-on CPUs, meaning permanent and irreplaceable.

Good luck! Remember: Stop if something doesn’t fit. Never force anything - you might regret it.

Comment: Will there be any differences in terms of performance if I do the swap?

Comment: @RedzaImran0480 Yes, see [Here](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i5-430M-vs-Intel-Core-i3-380M) for more information.

Comment: The i5 is quite expensive but when turbo boosted, both i5 and i3 will have the same frequency so I don't think swapping will make any difference

Comment: I do have a spare i5 but sadly the TDP is high AF. Got a new laptop anyway. Thanks for answering my inquiries!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your given information, it would appear that this is possible.

Neither of the CPU's are soldered in on those laptop models and they are both socket PGA988 so no problems there. (There is a BGA1288 version of the i5 which is soldered but I don't believe that Compaq model uses the BGA socket.)

Also, I am not certain if a BIOS update would be necessary. I suspect not but it may be a consideration for you.